# What is the "profile views" section in my profile for?

Tags: support, profile-page

I'm very confused regarding the "profile views" section in Stack Overflow.

[image]

Is it the number of profiles I have visited, or the number of times other developers have visited my profile to know more about me?

Does gaining more profile views increase reputation?

Comment: *"Is it related to number of profile I have visited or how many times other devloper have visited my profile to know more about me?"* - The latter, *"Does gaining more profile view increases our reputation?"* - No

Comment: Should I be bothered about it? Not really, unless you have a link in your profile that is a rick roll.

Comment: Side note: unusually high number may indicate that a lot of people found the account's behavior suspicious and tried to investigate what is going on... 39 views seem to be on par with other users with similar rep - https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=15000&tab=reputation&filter=all... So basically you are not a special. Whether it should bother you or not is totally up to you... but there there is likely Stack Exchange to discuss just that :)